# Chat scroll(recycler view) not smooth because of variable size image loading?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a chat application. Where I have different layouts for receive messages and send messaged. I am not able to get smooth scroll maybe because of variable image size? I think this issue related to layout I have made for the chat message box.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="right"
>


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingHorizontal="11dp"
            android:paddingVertical="9dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:text="fdsfdsfsdfs"
            tools:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#2A2617"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
        />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_message"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_message"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:padding="11dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

It flickers when i scroll up. Code of View  Holder is as follow

```
when(data.messageType){
     Constant.MessageType.TEXT ->{
          messageIv.visibility = View.GONE
          messageTv.apply {
              visibility = View.VISIBLE
              text = data.content
          }
     }
     Constant.MessageType.IMAGE -> {
          Glide.with(messageIv.context)
                .load(data.content)
                .apply(
                    RequestOptions()
                        .apply {
                            diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            skipMemoryCache(true)
                        })
                .into(messageIv)

          messageIv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
          messageTv.apply {
                visibility = View.GONE
          }
      }
}
```

I guess it call bind every time i scroll and it makes the visibility gone and visible. Which cause the view to have 0dp size for some amount of time and suddenly when image loads, it creates a sudden scroll in the view making it very unstable.

Any work-around for this?

Comment: Don't reuse same `ViewHolder`s for both image and text messages. Split them into multiple `itemViewType`s with their own layouts.

Comment: @Pawel Hi. Can you explain a little bit about why that should not be the case? Thanks.